# Disabling internal wifi adapter help

Tags: 14.04, wireless, networking

So I have been trying to disable my internal wifi adapter and I'm stuck on what another forum post told me to do.
They said

> "Unless there is a hardware switch to turn it off, just blacklist the
>   module.
>
> You can find out which module is in use with this:
>
> lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net
>
> ...to blacklist a module, add blacklist
>   module_name to /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf"

So I entered `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net` but how do I identify the wifi adapter 'module_name'?

My reseults from lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net:

```
:~$ lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net
01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:3971]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169

02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) [168c:002b] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:30a1]
    Kernel driver in use: ath9k
```

Answer (score 1):

> Qualcomm Atheros AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express)
>   [168c:002b] (rev 01) Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:30a1] Kernel
>   driver in use: ath9k

The wireless module name is ath9k. To blacklist it, instead of manually editing a file, let's take the easy way. Open a terminal and do:

```
sudo -i
echo "blacklist ath9k"  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
modprobe -r ath9k
exit
```

It might take a reboot.